# Custom AutoNumber

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am converting an excel spreadsheet over to an Access database.  I am new to Access, though I have taken a couple of courses through a local training company.  In the spreadsheet that I am converting, we currently use a "tracking" number that identifies each main record (which would be in my new main table) that is in the format of "YY-XXXX" where "YY" is the current 2-digit year and "XXXX" is a sequence number that begins at 0001 and could go up to 9999 each year.  So, the last record of 2014 might have been 14-1025, and the first record of 2015 is 15-0001.

For consistency sake with my old data, I would like to use the same numbering system.  I know I can generate a standard autonumber as the primary key (and I may do that as well anyway, but I want to have this YY-XXXX field automatically sequence when I create a new record in a form.  So, how might you recommend an approach to do this?

My first thought is to create and merge two strings, one that converts the current date to a two digit text field and the other an autonumber for the sequence?  I have played around with this and haven't been able to get anything to work.  I am not too good at VBA code, so it has all been just trying to create tables, fields and expressions.  But maybe VBA is the only way to do it.

While I don't know how to do this, one acceptable option might include using an autonumber that is six digits long and is just formatted with a dash after the first two digits, along with a way to easily restart the numbering, i.e. on Jan 1 of next year, set the autonumber to 160001 (formatted as 16-0001).

Any great ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

I have set up similar systems several times. It is always simpler to concatenate two values, than to split them apart. As you mentioned, use an autonumber for your PK. Then create two separate integer (not text) fields - TrackYear, TrackSequence and set a unique index on the combination of the two.
In the BeforeUpdate (NOT BeforeInsert) event of your form add the following:

```
If Me.NewRecord Then
ME!TrackYear = Format(Date,"YY")
Me!TrackSequence = Nz(DMax("TrackSequence",<yourTable>,"TrackYear=" & Format(Date,"YY")),0) + 1
End If
```

Create a query based on your table, including all fields, plus another calculated column TrackingNbr: TrackYear & "-" & Format(TrackSequence,"0000").
Anywhere you want to see the TrackingNbr, use this query.
For your import from the Excel sheet, you will need to split apart the existing numbers, but that is a one time thing. You can either write a formula in Excel, or do it in the append query in Access, whichever you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I like your idea. Had also to set up this system a few years ago, but stupid young me believed the IT department saying that double keys would have big performance issues.  Did you experience performance issues in ACCESS with your systems?

Comment: There is NOT a double key (to use your term). The PK is the autonumber, NOT the unique index. For any child tables, the FK would join to the autonumber of the parent, NOT the two fields. As for IT's comment (if it was a double key), it depends. Performance with a number key is typically better than a text field, So which would be better a single text field or two number fields? It depends!

Comment: I don't think you really need to to create query as, in Access 2013, you can create a calculated fields in the table , and set up it's calculation expression to concatenate two other fields in the same row.  (you could also use data macros to populate a "normal field".

Comment: Ups, yes I got it. I overread that you meant "unique index", not PK. Okay I forgot it is called a "composite key" Do not use that often... Thx for the info.

Comment: HarveyFrench, yes, you are correct. However, I don't use either calculated fields or data macros, since I haven't found any method to create/modify/delete them via code. When I need to make schema changes in the BE, I provide a small Access app that connects to the BE and makes the needed changes. That would not be possible using calculated fields or data macros.

Comment: asdev, I didn't mean to pick on your term. At the time, I just couldn't think of the correct term, which, as you stated is 'composite key'.

Comment: ( cc: @HarveyFrench ) - Both Calculated Fields and Data Macros can indeed be manipulated from code using Access DAO and the Application object's `SaveAsText`/`LoadFromText` methods respectively.

Comment: @AVG Do not worry, I did not feel offended. I really had to laugh when I read over the term again because I literally translated it into english.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Tracking Number is of a standard format and padded with 0s, it should be easy to get the last one per given year, split the two parts, increment the sequence portion, and return the next one.

Here's how I would do it.

Paste this into a new Module. (Be sure to change **MainTable** to the name of your main table and **TRACKING_NO** to your tracking number column name)

```
Function GetNextTrackingNo(Optional nYear As Long = 0) As String 'be sure to pass nYear as 2 digit year if you ever use that option!
  Dim strLastTN As String     'get the last tracking number per given year
  Dim nSEQ As Long

  If nYear = 0 Then nYear = Year(Now) - 2000 'year was not passed so use current year; -2000 should be fine until year 2100

  'Get the last Tracking number for the given year
  strLastTN = Nz(DMax("TRACKING_NO", "MainTable", "Left([TRACKING_NO],2) = '" & nYear & "'"), 0)

  'get the sequence number from the string
  nSEQ = CLng(Right(strLastTN, 4))

  'increment the sequence so you get the next one.
  nSEQ = nSEQ + 1

  'you might want to have a check here to see if next sequence is greater than 9999!

  'return the next tracking number in the desired format
   GetNextTrackingNo = Format(nYear, "00") & "-" & Format(nSEQ, "0000")

End Function
```

You can test it in another function:

```
Function TestGetNextTrackingNo()

  MsgBox GetNextTrackingNo 'show the next tracking number for this year
  MsgBox GetNextTrackingNo(14)  ' show the next tracking number for last year
  MsgBox GetNextTrackingNo(16) 'show next tracking number for next year

End Function
```

You can utilize the function within a form using the Form_BeforeInsert (Change **TRACKING_NO** to your tracking number column name)

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
  Me.TRACKING_NO = GetNextTrackingNo
End Sub
```

or if you want to use a date field in the current record to specify the year use this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
  Me.TRACKING_NO = GetNextTrackingNo  Year(me.MyDateControl)-2000
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that it is appropriate to use Form_BeforeInsert only if the record will never have it's date changed!  If you might change the date you shoudl use Form_BeforeUpdate.

Comment: This is very nice code and a good solution.  It is worth adding that I would not advise using the tracking number as a primary key. I would use a access auto number field as the PK.  Also, create a unique index on the tracking number.   I want to really very strongly suggest that you ALWAYS use a autonumber field as your primary key. There are so many benefits. I ALWAYS name it ID. I name any foreign keys in other tables that refer to it as TheTableNameWithTheFieldID. eg MyMainTableID. It really helps as you can easily see what is going on!